# cheapest price for product in month

Tags: sql, rdbms

I have a product_prices table

```
ID      Product_id     Price   Price_date
1            1           5      2021-10-01
2            1           6      2021-10-25
3            2           5      2021-10-01
4            2           6      2021-10-25
5            1           3      2021-09-01
6            1           5      2021-09-25
7            2           7      2021-09-01
8            2           3      2021-09-25
```

How i can get record what has cheapest price for product in each month by SQL query

```
ID      Product_id     Price   Price_date
1            1           5      2021-10-01
3            2           5      2021-10-01
5            1           3      2021-09-01
8            2           3      2021-09-25
```

Comment: [Why should I "tag my RDBMS"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you show us some code?

Comment: unfortunately I couldn't figure out how to do it so there is no code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've not tagged which RDBMS you're using, but if it's SQL Server, here's an example solution:

```
declare @product_prices table (
    ID int,
    Product_id int,
    Price int,
    Price_date date
)

insert into @product_prices values
(1,1,5,'2021-10-01'),
(2,1,6,'2021-10-25'),
(3,2,5,'2021-10-01'),
(4,2,6,'2021-10-25'),
(5,1,3,'2021-09-01'),
(6,1,5,'2021-09-25'),
(7,2,7,'2021-09-01'),
(8,2,3,'2021-09-25')

select
    datepart(year,Price_date) as [Year],
    datepart(month,Price_date) as [Month],
    datename(month,Price_date) as [MonthName],
    Product_id,
    min(Price) as LowestPrice
from @product_prices
group by
    datepart(year,Price_date),
    datepart(month,Price_date),
    datename(month,Price_date),
    Product_id
order by 1, 2
```

Results:

```
/-----------------------------------------------------\
| Year | Month | MonthName | Product_id | LowestPrice |
|------|-------|-----------|------------|-------------|
| 2021 |   9   | September |      1     |      3      |
| 2021 |   9   | September |      2     |      3      |
| 2021 |  10   | October   |      1     |      5      |
| 2021 |  10   | October   |      2     |      5      |
\-----------------------------------------------------/
```

Comment: Wow! I'm impressed. How did you determine that the OP is using SQL Server database?

Comment: I don't know for sure, as you pointed out in your comment, they didn't tag their RDBMS. But if it is MSSQL, then this gives them a possible answer and if it isn't, the concepts are likely to apply to other RDBMSes as well, albeit perhaps with different syntax.

Comment: thanks. how can I also display the date when this price was. In this case I must use join?

Comment: Is it possible for a given Product to hold the same (lowest) price on multiple dates in the same month? If so, how do you want to choose which date to return?